# I'm not gaining more reputation

Tags: support

Anybody can explain what is going here?!

Eventhough my answers is going upvoted but I'm not gaining any more reputation.

[image]

Comment: Why is everyone so worried about reputation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is because you have reached the daily cap from up-votes of 200.

Bounties and accepted answers are excluded from this calculation.

https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from any combination of the activities below. Only bounty awards and accepted answers are not subject to the daily reputation limit.

Comment: But I offer a bounty and now my reputation is less than 200 and still same

Comment: @Hadi bounties don't affect that. The rep cap is about how much rep you gain. If you give some away, that does not change the fact that you gained 200.

Comment: @terdon Ok friend I got it thanks